# Team Foundation Server 2018 User is missing contact information of Exchange

Tags: tfs, active-directory, exchange-server

We are trying to setup a TFS 2018 Update3.2 as ticketing system based on CMMI. I tried several things and begin to understand how everything works, except one very important thing.

We want to use the notifications and the emails are send correctly to 2 of 4 users. 1 user has no email, so that's ok, but me (my own account), don't gets any emails. I tried to set my email address by hand in the field: My Profile -> Preferred email. But that doesn't work either.

When I open a group with all users and click on them, I get to see the initials of my name and my full name. When I click on one of the working accounts, there are also contact informations (an email address and the possibility to start a sip chat.

So I looked into our Exchange (seems to make sense), but I don't have found any differences between my settings and those of the working accounts. I am also searching here now for more than an hour, so I don't think that the service still has to update.

Anyone an idea where I could look? How do I get my email address from the AD to the TFS? Or maybe how can I force a synchronization? Or delete all cache items and reload everything by it?

EDIT:
I killed the cache directory (the GUID-directory inside) and then everything got relaoded and now I get emails too.

Comment: Does your AD profile have an email address in it?

Comment: Yes, it does. I added the solution in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clear the cache, the problem is solved.